# Problems with Ajax-request via Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, logic

I have a big problem with Ajax-request via Laravel. I can't understand why it is not Ajax. All resources here.

It is my Ajax-request.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var nickname = "<?php echo $name_user; ?>";

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $('.subscribe').click(function() {
             jQuery.ajax({
                   type: 'post',
                   url: "{{ route('postSubscribe', '<?php echo $name_user; ?>') }}", //Путь к обработчик
                   data: {'user_name': nickname},
                   response: 'text',
                   success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data['result']);
                   },
                   error: alert('Error');
               })
        })
    </script>
```

It is my web-routes.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
Route::get('/', 'AccountController@redirectToAccountPage');
Route::get('/account', 'AccountController@showAccount')->name('account');
Route::get('/account/settings', 'AccountController@showSettings')->name('settings');
Route::post('/account/settings', 'AccountController@sendSetting');
Route::get('/account/subscribe', 'AccountController@showSubscriberForm')->name('subscriber');
Route::post('/account/subscribe', 'AccountController@findUser')->name('postFindUser');
Route::get('/account/load_image', 'AccountController@showLoadImage')->name('load_image');
Route::post('/account/load_image', 'Photos\LoadPhotoController@loadPhoto');
Route::post('/account/logout', 'AccountController@logout')->name('logout');

Route::post('/user/{user_name}/', 'AccountController@subscribe')->name('postSubscribe');
Route::get('/admin', 'AccountController@showAdminPanel');
```

});

It's my main request.

```
public function subscribe(Request $request, $name_user) {
    if($request->ajax()) {
        $query = 'SELECT id FROM subscriptions WHERE id_subscriber = ? AND id_subscribtion = ?';
        $queryFindAnother = 'SELECT id From new_users WHERE nickname = ?';
        $idAnotherUser = DB::select($queryFindAnother, [$name_user]);
        if(!DB::select($query, [Auth::user()->id, $idAnotherUser[0]->id])) {
            $query = 'INSERT INTO subscriptions (id_subscriber, id_subscribtion) VALUES (?, ?)';
            dd('Я здесь');
            //id_subscriber - тот, кто подписался.
            //id_subscribtion - на кого подписан.
            DB::insert($query, [Auth::user()->id, $idAnotherUser[0]->id]);
            return response()->json([
                'result' => '1', //всё прошло успешно, я подписан
            ]);
        }

        return back();
    }

    dd("It's not ajax");
    return back();
}
```

As a result I got the message "It's not Ajax". Help me please!

Comment: please add the element of HTML which is associated with .subscribe class

Comment: `url: "{{ route('postSubscribe', '<?php echo $name_user; ?>') }}",` ... this looks like you mixing things up. Try just `{{ route('postSubscribe', $name_user) }}",` instead.

Comment: @emtiaz-zahid, it already exists.
<form method="post" action="">
 {!! csrf_field() !!}
 <button class="subscribe" name="user">Подписаться.</button>
</form>

Maybe my problem can be connected with empty action but I have a route...

Comment: @peter, your way to solve my problem is not working. Try to help me again. Thank you for your previous way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your form

Please update your form

```
<form> 
{!! csrf_field() !!} 
<button class="subscribe" name="user" type="button">Подписаться.</button> 
</form>
```

Here, you don't need any action or method also does not need any form

because you passing the form data as ajax

and add the type of your button as `button`, by default its a submit type, so its submitting the form as normally.

Comment: I changed the button into the input with type = submit but it doesn't work. Thanks anyway for your solution.

Maybe the problem can be connected with X-CSRF-TOKEN when I send the Ajax-request.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported the **Request** Facade on top

Comment: I added "use Illuminate\Support\Facades" at the top of the page where there is Ajax-request and where I have my main request but it doesn't work. Thanks anyway for your solution.